# sorting columns of html table in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting

I have a requirement where I need to sort each column of table every time it is clicked in ascending order. The logic applied is a general logic for sorting in Javascript. It works fine in all the scenarios except when the data comes up with different digits the column.

The code is

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy'
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(records: Array<any>, args?: any): any {

    return records.sort(function(a, b){

      if(a[args.property] === null){
        return 1 * args.direction;
      }
      else if(b[args.property] === null){
        return -1 * args.direction;
      }
      else if(a[args.property] < b[args.property]){
        return -1 * args.direction;
      }
      else if( a[args.property] > b[args.property]){
        return 1 * args.direction;
      }
      else{
        return 0;
      }
    });
  };

}
```

the above code fails when I get data like 844401, 76574893632,717613, 6304420005555

It sorts the values in the order listed above although it should sort 76574893632 before 844401

Comment: As a side not, the angular team discourages the use of pipes for filtering or ordering. You can read more [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe).

Comment: then how do you sort

Comment: Inside your component. Depending on your needs, either when you receive the array from your service you sort it and then display it, or if it's displayed already and you want to order on click, you take the array, order it and display again.

Comment: This is exactly what i am doing but does not sort in correct order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting
>   them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order. For
>   example, "Banana" comes before "cherry". In a numeric sort, 9 comes
>   before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes
>   before "9" in Unicode order.

Given the fact that on provided code here you take as parameter an Array of type `any`, I could not tell what you supply to the pipe, that is left for you to figure out.

But, I'll explain you what possibilities you have:

- you supply an Array of string in the form of `["844401", "76574893632", "717613", "6304420005555"]` and you apply `.sort()` on it, the result is going to be `6304420005555,717613,76574893632,844401`
- you supply an Array of numbers in form of `[844401, 76574893632, 717613, 6304420005555]` and you apply `.sort()` on it, it will treat them as `Unicode` values, thus resulting in a sort applied to strings and the result is going to be the same as before: `6304420005555,717613,76574893632,844401`
- the third one, which I assume is the one you are looking for, is to supply an Array of numbers in form of `[844401, 76574893632, 717613, 6304420005555]`, then you have to apply the sort method with a supplied compareFunction in order to be treated like numbers: `.sort( (a,b) => { return a-b } )`. Then you have the result: `717613,844401,76574893632,6304420005555`

I have made an implementation for you on plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/jkmtttvMg8i4b0befoFz?p=preview).

Hope it's clearer now. If you have further questions, don't hesitate.

Comment: This is something that explains why it behaved abruptly. Thanks for your detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that your number comparisons are being done with the values properly parsed as integers rather than strings. Comparing two numbers in the form of strings will not necessarily produce what you would expect.

Comment: Even if I use below code, the behavior does not change
  selectedData.sort(function (a,b) {

      if(isDesc) {
        return parseFloat(a.fndgSmssBchId) - parseFloat(b.fndgSmssBchId);
      }
      else {
        return parseFloat(b.fndgSmssBchId) - parseFloat(a.fndgSmssBchId);
      }
    })